# Conflicting HERE sdk and Fresco library

Tags: android, here-api, fresco

I've just stumbled upon a very particular issue. There seem to be a conflict between some native libraries (i assume). When using the *HERE* premium SDK for android **and** Facebook's *Fresco* library in the same project will result in HERE map not rendering. As soon as i remove the *Fresco* library from my project it behaves and renders as it should.

Of course the simplest solution is not to use *Fresco* but i rather not do that.

Anyone any idea what is going on or how to solve this?

This is the error it throws:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected end of document
at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:125)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:107)
at com.nokia.maps.fh.a(XmlToDocParser.java:24)
at com.nokia.maps.ResourceManager.a(ResourceManager.java:212)
at com.nokia.maps.ResourceManager.a(ResourceManager.java:138)
at com.nokia.maps.as.<init>(GLConfigHelper.java:38)
at com.nokia.maps.y.a(BaseTextureView.java:61)
at com.nokia.maps.y.<init>(BaseTextureView.java:54)
at com.nokia.maps.bx.<init>(MapTextureView.java:36)
at com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapView.a(MapView.java:320)
at com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:169)
at com.nokia.maps.bk.a(MapFragmentImpl.java:143)
at com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:147)
at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1060)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1162)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2131)
at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5751)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:78)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
at com.justpark.ondemand.ui.activity.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:20)
at com.justpark.ondemand.ui.activity.TurnByTurnActivity.onCreate(TurnByTurnActivity.java:145)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6500)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: check which support dependencies extending by each one of them is conflicting and try to remove them.

Comment: Fresco doesn't really have any dependencies except for android support lib. As for HERE, it's a jar file with some native .so files. i went through Fresco's source real quick but couldn't find anything similiar.

Comment: Any version info ? Tried a simple app with HERE SDK Peremium v 3.0.1  and fresco-v0.7.0 , but didn't see this issue.

Comment: Yes, that's the versions i used. Weird... To be honest, i haven't tried a clean project to reproduce this. And i can only reproduce it in my project if i add the project. I don't really have the time to investigate deeply (hence i asked here) and went with another image lib for now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Fresco has a file called eglconfig.xml, that file must also be present in fresco resources or in your app? If you delete this xml file from the resource tree, does it help?

/I'm from the HERESDK team and thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply didn't have the time to look into this until now. Anyway, i just checked if that file is in the packaged APK file. There's no such file found.

Comment: It was used internally in the SDK to store some EGL config quirks on legacy devices. With newer editions this code has been removed.